# ag-Grid: how to trigger revalidation on dependent cells

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, ag-grid

I have a `mother cell` and a `child cell` in my ag-grid. In order to find the right child with the right mother, I compare the mother with the child and check if they have the same familyId. So far so good. I do that for the mother cell and for the child cell. So the one that gets edited later throws an error with wrong ID if they don't have the same familyId.

Problem: I just added the child after the mother and I am sure I've chosen the right child, but I get the error "not same family ID" because I had a typo in the mother cell. I have the error showing up in the child cell.

If I update the mother cell the validation runs and I get as a result that I found the right mother and child. But the thing is the error in the child cell doesn't update. Meaning the error still shows unless I click the children cell to revalidate and exit the cell again.

btw I am using a cellRenderer to do the validation and display of the possible errors.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the relationship between mother and child cells? Do you refer to [master - detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/)?

Comment: Hi, no I don't use master-detail I just use the Id of mother and child to filter the query and look if they have the same family id.